# Unable to stop iframe from loading

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am not able to stop an iframe from loading. There are similar questions but none of the solutions really work.

I created a page which has an `iframe` and two buttons. When clicking the first button it sets `src` attribute, the 2nd button tries to stop `iframe` from loading by calling:

```
    f.src = 'about:blank';
    f.contentWindow.stop();
```

The code is here https://glitch.com/edit/#!/heavenly-bathtub

You can play it here https://heavenly-bathtub.glitch.me/

**The issue is visible when the iframe loads its page very slow. This can be mimicked in Chrome for example by the Network tab**. The steps are these:

1. Navigate to https://heavenly-bathtub.glitch.me/
2. In Chrome, go to Network tab and choose Slow 3G from the speed presets.
3. Make sure you can see the Console
4. Click on 'Start Load' and then immediately click on 'Stop Load'
5. You can see the page still being loaded in the frame!

Comment: When you click on the start, the request is sent to the url you want and even when you click on stop, still your browser is waiting for the response from the server and when it gets the response, it will overwrite the content of the `iframe` with the response. So you have to implement a mechanism that when you receive the response, then check if before that the stop button has been clicked or not, if so, then do not load the content in the `iframe`. The best practice to implement this is using `ajax get` instead of loading the url directly in the `iframe src`

Comment: If you want, I can create a simple code snippet for you to give you a clue how it works

Comment: @EhsanT The issue is there doesn't seem to be a way to make an iframe cancel the request, even navigating it to something 'about:blank' won't do it. Which is very strange.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to actually stop it from loading? Could you not just remove the iframe completely or navigate to a different page entirely?

Comment: Thanks. This is the solution I already consider, but I am looking to understand why `stop()` nor setting `src` to `about:blank`  don't work

Comment: Fair enough. It's an odd one and I can't see the solution. I'll keep thinking